# How to use tlb in visual c++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com

I have an interface [c#] called `IronMan` and `RonMan` implements the `IronMan`.

The problem is that i can't create an instance [VC++] of the `RonMan`:

Interface:

```
namespace Widex.RonMan.Interop
{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("5A3F9483-E235-4C92-839A-5890E60FD165")]
  public interface IronMan
  {
    int GetSome(int some);
  }
}
```

the ronman class:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Widex.RonMan
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("79FD9A2F-AE4B-4412-BE8G-00649E136FCK")]
public class RonMan : IRonMan
{
    public  int GetSome(int some)
    {
        return some;
    }
}
```

When I try to use it:

```
    [TestMethod]
    void IronManTest()
    {
        auto romManAuto= IRonManPtr(_uuidof(RonMan));
        auto res = romManAuto-> GetSome(2);

        Assert::AreEqual(2,res);
    }
```

following exception is created:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
```

**UPDATE:** 
COM initialization:

```
#pragma once
#pragma unmanaged 
#import "Company.Heroes.Interop.tlb" no_namespace named_guids rename("value", "valueEx") 
// Following code is managed code. 
#pragma managed
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread GetSome().  You need try/catch in your C++ code to catch the [_com_error exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ye3k36s.aspx).  It is a goody you get from using the smart pointer (IRonManPtr), it turns error codes in exceptions.  Probably something plebeian like not being able to find the registry key or DLL.  Switching the debugger to mixed-mode also works to diagnose C# exceptions.

Comment: Do you have [assembly: ComVisible(true)] in your Assembly configuration? You may also need [assembly: Guid("...")].

Comment: It's also not clear if you've initialised COM in your C++ test code.

Comment: @gigaplex I have update the question. in my opinion the com is initialized correctly.

Comment: That update doesn't  initialise the COM runtime, that's importing the typelib to get the interface definitions. You may need to call something like CoInitialize() or CoInitializeEx() if the program hasn't initialised it already.

Comment: Are you using C++/CLR or Native C++? It looks like you are using C++/CLR. If C++/CLR you don't need to use a type library to use a c# class, you should use #using instead.